Maximum area triangle inside non-convex polygon with one of its sides being an edge of the polygon
There seem to be multiple resources for finding the largest triangle inside a convex polygon.
My problem is a bit different and I hope I can find some guidance here.
Given a simple non-convex polygon and two vertices A and B which are an edge of the polygon, I want to find point C inside (or on the boundary of) the polygon so that the area of the triangle ABC becomes maximal.
That is, no part of the polygon should be cut off and all three edges of the triangle shall not cross any polygon edge (touching is ok).
Example: The purple polygon is non-convex and points A, B are given.

My guess is that the touching points $T_1$ and $T_2$ need to be considered in the construction. The touching points are those "concave points" of the polygon (concave points are those with interior angle $>180°$) which the triangle edges from A to C (and B to C) touch first (before any other concave point is touched). But I figured out that the intersection point of the rays from A through $T_1$ and from $B$ to $T_2$ does not have to lie inside the polygon so that this is not the right solution, see next image.

How can I identify point C so that the area of the triangle becomes maximal and the triangle lies fully inside the polygon?
In the previous example, I would expect something like this:

Notice that C does not coincide with one of the vertices of the polygon, which is fine and expected.


You are not looking for a closed formula (which surely doesn't exist) but for an algorithm, even if you don't use the word... 2) In your title "with two fixed points" should be "one of its sides being an edge of the polygon".


Yes, both statements are correct.

A basic remark : for a given edge AB of the polygon, the locus of points C such that the area of CAB is constant is a line parallel to AB (then in a second step, we have to care for the "feasability" of point C).
